# jQuery checkbox.prop cannot trigger checkbox.on('change', function)

Tags: jquery

I try to use checkbox.prop('checked', true) to trigger checkbox.on('change', function). But failed.
More details as below:
https://jsbin.com/jibeboviso/edit?html,js,output

```js
var checkbox = jQuery("#selectAll");
checkbox.on('change', function() {
  alert('changed');
});
// change checkbox prop, cannot trigger `change` event
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: It does work in your jsbin example... what browser are you using? Either way, you can add checkbox.trigger('change')

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to do but when i check if the prop function work, it work

```js
var checkbox = jQuery('#selectAll');
checkbox.on('change', function() {
  alert('changed');
});

// change checkbox prop, cannot trigger `change` event
checkbox.prop('checked', true);

if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
    alert('checked');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">select all</input>
</body>
</html>
```